# how to call a aspx URL form angular

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular

Need to call a aspx URL which return value. that URL is following:

Here I called like this:
const result =  HttpClient.get('https://baseurl/CapturePay.aspx?orderid=orderid&amount=amount&msisdn=msisdn');

If i hit this URL directly in browser then get response. but not using above way.

Just trying to do this in angular end:

```
string url = BasicSetting.PaymentApiUrl + $"CapturePay.aspx?orderid={vm.PaymentId}&amount={vm.PaidAmount}&msisdn={vm.Phone}";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
                    var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    if (res != "Captured")
                    {
                        result.Status = Status.BadRequest; result.Message = "Invalid payment info";
                        result.Error = res;
                       
                    }
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: Angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: I'll check your URL and it is not working "https://baseurl/CapturePay.aspx?orderid=orderid&amount=amount&msisdn=msisdn"